# Как получить нужный элемент массива? php

Tags: php

```
foreach ($manga as $key => $item) {

       
        if($g == $item["glava"]) $glavaPrevStop = true;
       
        if($glavaPrevStop == false) {
            $glavaPrev = $item["glava"];
        } }
```

Массив в моем случае выглядит примерно так
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2

Выше конструкция для присваивания переменной $glavaPrev предыдущего элемента массива.
Загвоздка в том, что когда я нахожусь на последнем элементе (из примера это 2) и иду назад, переменной присваивается сразу 1, потом 0 (пока все как и должно быть) и за 0 сразу 7, а не 9. Он увидел по проходу цикла первый 0 и за него сразу зацепился. Как сделать так, чтобы он получал 9?

Comment: В чём смысл вообще всего того, что Вы делаете? Что-то тут вообще не понятно, какие-то цифры, по какому-то принципу присваивается true, исходя из этого не присваивается значение, зачем-то массив проходит вперёд, потом назад.

Comment: Это переключение глав манги. Цифры - номер главы.

Comment: Вначале сформируйте в голове у себя суть проблемы и попытайтесь ее объяснить самому себе, но так словно Вы вообще не в курсе задачи. После этого уже распишите ее сообществу и попросите помощи. А то со стороны видно лишь кусок кода вырванный из контекста задачи, нет описания задачи, нет входных данных и есть просьба за Вас найти ошибку в коде. Сами-то Вы смогли бы с таким описанием кому-то помочь?